# How to detect encodings on signed integers in C?

Tags: c, signed, twos-complement, ones-complement

The ISO C standard allows three encoding methods for signed integers: two's complement, one's complement and sign/magnitude.

What's an efficient or good way to detect the encoding at runtime (or some other time if there's a better solution)? I want to know this so I can optimise a bignum library for the different possibilities.

I plan on calculating this and storing it in a variable each time the program runs so it doesn't have to be blindingly fast - I'm assuming the encoding won't change during the program run :-)

Comment: You will never need to do this at run-time - it's purely a compile-time issue when compiling for a specific architecture.

Comment: For bignum libraries you almost always want unsigned types anyway. While you might be able to use a signed type for the highest order word, it's probably simpler to just store a separate sign bit and always work with positive numbers, and then flip the sense of addition/subtraction depending on the sign bit. Basically your own sign/magnitude representation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You just have to check the low order bits of the constant `-1` with something like `-1 & 3`. This evaluates to

1. for sign and magnitude,
2. for one's complement and
3. for two's complement.

This should even be possible to do in a preprocessor expression inside `#if #else` constructs.

Comment: @Answer of Jens Gustedt Very Nice! But during cross-compilation, what exactly is checked here, the encoding of the compiler (preprocessor) or of the target machine?

Comment: @user2596047, a compiler must always evaluate all expressions as if they were evaluated at run time, such that the execution of the generate code behaves the same as in the so-called "abstract state machine". So yes, even for cross-compilation, this has to be done in the arithmetic of the target machine, not the host machine.

Answer (score 12):

Detecting one's complement should be pretty simple -- something like `if (-x == ~x)`. Detecting two's complement should be just about as easy: `if (-x == ~x + 1)`. If it's neither of those, then it must be sign/magnitude.

Comment: These are constant expressions too, so you can use them in `#if` tests: `#define TWOSCOMPLEMENT (~-1 == 0)` then `#if TWOSCOMPLEMENT`.

Comment: your expressions are not necessarily true for all cases of `x` though, so you should be careful with border cases. In particular there is this nasty case for two's complement where `-x` provokes undefined behavior, namely `-INT_MIN` may be out of bounds.

Answer (score 2):

Why not do it at compile time? You could have the build scripts/makefile compile a test program if need be, but then use the preprocessor to do conditional compilation.  This also means performance is *much* less important, because it only runs once per compile, rather than once per run.

Answer (score 0):

Get a pointer to to an int that would show a distinctive bit-pattern.  Cast it as a pointer to unsigned int and then examine the bit values.

Doing this with a couple of carefully chosen values should do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you'd store a negative number as an `int` into a `char` array large enough to hold it and compare the array with the various representations to find out.

But uhm... unsigned integers should not have a sign, do they ?

Comment: Yeah... seems I was thinking too complicated... Jerry's right about using bit operations to check. Never mind. Leaving it here as an alternative answer.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that should have been signed.